# Module of side-script, which is imported in django views.py can not find weights file with tensorflow's load_weights func

Tags: django, tensorflow

I have a django application, which contains activation an imported side-script from another project, when it gets an image file in POST-request. Side-script calls another script, which uses tensorflow function load_weights to load pre-trained weights and apply a super-resolution trained model to image, then i expect to return enchanced version of it in views.py and transfer back to html page in response.

The problem, however, is that for some reason module of side-script can not find weights file (no such file or directory error), while if i run it directly (not calling from django project) it finds it perfectly fine. Does anyone have a solution?

Python version 3.7
tensorflow version 2.3.1
Django version 3.2.19

I have tried to move weights file to script's folder so it wouldn't be necessary to give it full path anymore, just a file name, but it did not work, so i can not figure any solution for now.

Django's views. py:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from .NetworksProject.globalExec import globalExec

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES:
        file = request.FILES['image1']
        networkType = request.POST['networkType']
        print(file)
        print(networkType)
        print(globalExec(file, networkType))
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(file.name, file)
        file_url = fs.url(filename)
        return render(request, 'NeuralSR_App/index.html', {'file_url': file_url})

    return render(request, 'NeuralSR_App/index.html')
```

My side-script globalExec.py:

```
from .a_edsr import edsrFunc
from .a_wdsr import wdsrFunc
from .a_srgan import srganFunc

def globalExec(source, networktype):

    lowResglobalSource = source
    highResGlobalSource = 'demo/manHR.jpg'

    if (networktype == 'edsrVal'):
        output = edsrFunc(lowResglobalSource, highResGlobalSource)

    if (networktype == 'wdsrVal'):
        output = wdsrFunc(lowResglobalSource, highResGlobalSource)

    if (networktype == 'srganVal'):
        output = srganFunc(lowResglobalSource, highResGlobalSource)

    return '123123'
```

Side-script's module a_edsr.py, which tries to load weights and apply a model to image:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
from .common import resolve_single
from .edsr import edsr

from .utils import load_image, plot_and_save_image

def edsrFunc(sourceLow, sourceHigh):
    filenameSourceInput = sourceLow
    filenameHighResSourceInput = sourceHigh

    model = edsr(scale=4, num_res_blocks=16)
    model.load_weights('weights/edsr-16-x4/weights.h5')

    #using a model, doesn't matter since it crashes on load_weights function

    return (sr)
```

Error text:
Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'weights/edsr-16-x4/weights.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)